# Disable Exchange 2013 OWA redirect

Tags: exchange, redirection, iis-8

I have an Exchange 2013 combined Mailbox/CAS server available in the web; let's assume it's under `http(s)://contoso.com/`. On that Exchange server, I have the IIS default website (iisstart.htm) installed.

- When I open `http://contoso.com`, I correctly see the `iisstart.htm`.
- When I open `https://contoso.com`, I am redirected to `https://contoso.com/owa/auth/logon.aspx?replaceCurrent=1&url=https%3a%2f%2fcontoso.com%2fowa%2f`.

The default web site does not contain a redirect. I cannot find how to disable the redirect.

How do I have to change the IIS settings such that `iisstart.htm` is shown whenever `https://contoso.com` is opened, and OWA is only shown whenever `https://contoso.com/owa` is opened?

Comment: Why did you need that? Did you try to host something else on your Exchange server via that approach? I wouldn´t do that. If this what you try to host there has a vulnerability it will infect your whole Exchange Server.

Comment: @BastianW (1) The decision is above my paygrade. (2) The thing hosted there will be - at least for now - a static web page with a bit of javascript, two images and half a dozen links.

Comment: Sure but you will be kicked if somebody can send bogus emails in the name from the CEO due to a non save exchange installation you manage ;-) (or a ddos attack against the strange website, which will then also kill exchange). So not every possible solution which might be possible should be implemented because somebody else think it's a clever idea. I would give them the advise to use a 3 euro hosting somewhere as working solution regardless if this is possible or not on an exchange server.